# How to send eFax fax through PHP?

Tags: php, phpmailer, fax

I am trying to send a fax via the eFax service. As I understand, this should be as easy as sending a simple email to the specific address.

I use PHPMailer for emails. Ordinary emails are sending fine. Even when I send to an efax address `$mail->send` returns *`true`*, that means that the email was sent seccessfully, but the recipient didn't receive the fax.

Any suggestions?

Thank you.

```
function sendFax($fax, $msg) {

$efax_number = $fax . "@efaxsend.com";

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';

$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;      

$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = EMAIL_HOST;                 //   Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                                             //   Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = EMAIL_SMTP_USERNAME;
$mail->Password = EMAIL_SMTP_PASSWORD;   //   SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                                          //   Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 587;
//From email address and name
$mail->From = "orders@orderapp.com";
$mail->FromName = "Test";


//To address and name
$mail->addAddress($efax_number);     // SEND EMAIL TO USER

//Send HTML or Plain Text email
$mail->isHTML(false);

$mail->Subject = ' New Order Fax ';

$mail->Body = $msg;
$mail->AltBody = "Sample";

$result = $mail->send();

if (!$result)
{
    ...
}
else
{
    ...
}
```

}

Comment: *But the recipient did receive fax* > So it did work?

Comment: _“Any suggestions?”_ - ask them (the eFax people)? We have no way of telling whether they received your email or not.

Comment: Of course you could also try and send an email from your normal email client first, and see if that gets you any different result ...

Comment: If your sending of the email is anything like your spelling and grammar abilities then you've probably made numerous simple mistakes.

Comment: Have you tried reading the PHPMailer debug output?

Comment: Have you tried telling the owner of the destination fax machine to climb out of 1994 and to get an email address instead?

Comment: ***Sending !== Receiving***

Comment: Contact `eFax` and ask them what's going on. Souds like a proprietory issue as PHPMailer is for sending *Emails* so the issue can be the receiving device is expecting a Fax data type rather than an email data type.

Comment: [eFax](http://efax.com) is an email to fax gateway, so it's expecting to receive an email. Setting `$mail->SMTPDebug = 2` will show you the response from whatever `EMAIL_HOST` is, but if that's not eFax directly, you will need to look at your mail server logs. All of this is covered in [the PHPMailer troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting).